# Can worksheet filters only be used in WHERE or GROUP BY Clause in Snow?flake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use the value selected in a filter as a returned column.

For instance like

```
SELECT :MyFilter;
```

but I get the following error:

```
No valid expression found for :Subscription. Expecting "<expression> = :MyFilter" (line 1)
```

Comment: How is MyFilter being populated - is it a passed value from a reporting platform?  You may need to declare a local variable, assign it the value from :MyFilter, and then use in your query.  See the following reference:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#working-with-variables

Comment: Funny you say that as this is how we worked around it afterwards. Interested to know whether there could be a more direct way...

Comment: I'm not aware of a more direct way, as the pattern is defined to use locally declared variables to assign the values from other constructs in order to manipulate or process further in coding.  If you found this to work, I'll move my earlier comment to the answer block, and this question can be closed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to declare a local variable, assign it the value from :MyFilter, and then use in your query. See the following reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#working-with-variables